# How do I determine the cause of a slow load times?

Tags: optimization, hosting, expressionengine, pagespeed

I have a network solutions hosting and ExpressionEngine.  I have a page which uses jquery isotope to display our products.  This page takes a significant amount of time to load.  I downloaded the "Yslow" FF plugin and have gone through optimizing according to these guidelines to the point that I get a 93 score.  Yet the page is still very slow.

- I have compressed all images with "smush.it"
- Set Etags and expires headers
- Combined and minified js and css
- Reduced the number of DOM elements
- Reduced the number of EE queries - down from 415 to 69 by removing
  playa fieldtype associations.
- css is at the top, js at bottom

Comment: It looks like you have already done a lot for your page optimization. Using Chrome Developer tools or the Firebug network tab, you should be able to point which resources are taking the most time to load. Sometimes you depend on external resources that are slowing the whole page.

Comment: How many products/images are you displaying?

Comment: How slow are we talking? Care to share a link?

Comment: One other common culprit is calls to third party sites (ads, embedded widgets, etc.).

Comment: I just realized you said "Network Solutions". Run away quickly. Their servers are not setup for dynamic sites - their database performance is terrible. Nothing you can do will fix this while you're there.

Comment: @DerekHogue - 56 products. Also would you have any ideas how I could test db performance? I would just like to have a prove-able way to say the problem is "A" or "B".

Comment: @AllInOne - [link](http://www.hexarmor.com/products) still a work in progress but was told to push it live and fix as I can.

Comment: @juddlyon - third parties would be Google Analytics and marketo both included at the bottom. No ads or widgets.

Comment: one easy way to benchmark db performance would be to load the page from the db and save the result to a file. upload that page to the server as a static page. compare load times of the static and dynamic page. use apache bench if you want to get fancy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked at the link you provided made one suggestion for benchmarking in the comments above.

Are you using Chrome Developer Tools as suggested by @kant312 ? Or better yet try [Google Canary](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs/) as the tools are next gen there.

Total payload in an unprimed browser cache is over 1.0MB and 74 total network requests.  This is a lot of data and a lot of requests.

Using that Chrome tool it looks like from a network point of view your worst offenders are:

http://www.hexarmor.com/automin/8ce57c337ec87d08b88c9da7c9fbb37b.js?modified=1338396875
this is a 154KB .js file and for some reason it is not being gzipped.

Your second biggest file is http://www.hexarmor.com/assets/img/background.jpg this is a 147KB image. The kind of noisy textured background you are using here does not compress well.  As to the compression algorithm it all looks like "important detail".  If you blur it slightly it might compress better.  But this is a design factor.

Third biggest file is http://www.hexarmor.com/automin/ede5907dc9f416131684b845fc597112.css?modified=1342712812 this is a 117KB CSS file. Again, highly compressible, but your server is not gzipping it.

I think by fixing these 3 files you could reduce the total payload by 200KB (20%). Fixing the gzipping of CSS and JS will apply to other files as well so that will give you further payload reduction automatically.

Here's the .htaccess line that we use for gzipping

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/x-js application/x-javascript text/javascript
```

There are a ton of extra rules that some folks use for handling edge cases (mostly older browsers) but this should get you started.

If you are going to show that many products on a page then you are going to have a lot of network requests for images.  Maybe you can lazy load the ones that are lower on the page?  Also consider combining your social buttons into a single sprite.

Comment: I noticed those were not gzipping and was not really sure why? I thought about lazy load but figured it could mess up the sorting and filtering.  I also used AJAX to load the larger image upon clicking the small image to get more info in an effort to save img downloads. Why would just 2 files not g zip? can I explictly zip them, sorry this concept is new to me and I included code in my .htaccess to accomplish this after seeing it as an issue in "Yslow" FF plugin. So I dont entirely understand how this works

Comment: I expect none of the .css or .js files hosted on your site are gzipped. You can turn this on in .htaccess. I'd recommend you do a little searching, or ask your hosting provider, and if you are stuck start a new question on this specific topic. Hope I have been helpful.

Comment: We are on basic shared hosting.  Would upgrading to VPS help? If so do you know how much?   I am having difficulty finding information to support this.  I understand the gained flexibility, but performance info is hard for me to find.

Comment: I am seeing long latency on the page request. This suggests that your site is constrained by db performance. So your choice is ask the db to do less (turn on EE caching, reduce the number of queries etc) or get a db that is better resourced. VPS is not necessarily the answer tho it may be. Currently you are on a shared web server that is talking to a shared db.  If you move to a VPS you are on a single virtual box running both web server and database on top of a shared host. If your current  host is overselling database in shared hosting what is to stop them from overselling the VPS as well?